# How does mathematica numerically evaluate the Meijer G-function?

Tags: numerics, special-functions, implementation-details

The Meijer G-function is defined as a contour integral in the complex plane. Mathematica is able to numerically evaluate such a function quickly and accurately. How does she do that?

Comment: Internal numerical algorithms that are not likely to be publicly viewable, is my understanding.

Comment: According to NIST, there seem to be some fortran libraries that calculate the Meijer G-function, see for example https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.27 , so if I could venture a guess, probably Mathematica uses either a wrapper around that or some similar implementation. The actual details are of course not publicly available.

Comment: Actually, by googling I found something and added it as an answer. I will update it if I find anything more.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this old draft](https://www-m3.ma.tum.de/bornemann/Numerikstreifzug/Chapter9/MeijerG.pdf) by Folkmar Bornemann, the implementation of Meijer G-function is a bit complicated and it happens in various stages. The article mentions a comment by Daniel Lichtblau on July 27, 2003:

> I'll  be  discussing  aspects  of  MeijerG  issues  at  ACA  next
> week.  It  is  basically  a  lookup  that  converts  various functions
> to  MeijerG,  then  figures  out  the  integral  of  a product of 2
> MeijerG's via Slater convolution.

Furthermore, the Notes on Internal Implementation say the following:

> Many  other  definite  integrals  are  done  using  Marichev--
> Adamchik  Mellin  transform  methods.  The  results  are  often
> initially  expressed  in  terms  of  Meijer  G  functions,  which are
> converted  into  hypergeometric  functions  using  Slater's Theorem
> and then simplified.

So in a nutshell, when one asks for the value of a Meijer G-function, this is converted to hypergeometric functions and then evaluated using the latter. The attached article also contains some mathematical details, that an interested reader may enjoy.

Comment: Many thanks for this answer! I looked up the references you mentioned, but it was not super helpful. I suppose that mathematica is just very good at summing the corresponding series.

Answer (score 5):

Contrary to the comments, alot of the implementation is actually viewable.
The evaluation seems to be a bit convoluted.
First there a a whole lot of definitions for special cases which then get converted into other forms. A lot of Bessel Functions, Pochhammer, SinIntegrals and Elliptic functions. If this does not match,
it gets into the gereral evaluation which seems to consist of alot of Hypergeometric functions and finding of poles (residuals of some kind maybe?)
But it seems extremely complex for various pathways of possible parameters.

If you want to read it yourself, type:

```
<<"GeneralUtilities`"
GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions@MeijerG
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: As already noted, `MeijerG[]` usually does a table lookup. In the event that doesn't work, it does numerical contour integration of the defining Mellin-Barnes integral, with specially chosen contours.