# How does Mathematica numerically evaluate Gaussian Hypergeometric function $_2F_1(a,b,c,z)$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: numerics, special-functions, implementation-details

[Gaussian hypergeometric function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hypergeometric2F1.html) $_2F_1(a,b,c,z)$ usually takes $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $z \in \mathbb{C}$. But using [Barnes integral representation](http://homepage.tudelft.nl/11r49/documents/wi4006/barnes.pdf), one can analytically continue the $_2F_1(a,b,c,z)$ function to $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$.

In Mathematica 12.3, I can directly calculate $_2F_1(a,b,c,z)$ for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$ by typing code like

```
N[Hypergeometric2F1[I, 2 I, 3, 4]]
```

which returns

```
-169.791 - 71.7173 I
```

However, the documentation page for $_2F_1(a,b,c,z)$ doesn't even mention evaluating the function is possible for complex $a,b,c$ values.

I want to write a code to evaluate Gaussian hypergeometric function in python for the complex values. For that I want to know is which numerical algorithm Mathematica uses to calculate the Gaussian hypergeometric function. Is it by using the Barnes Integral Representation or some other method?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: This might help: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/252822/how-does-mathematica-numerically-evaluate-the-meijer-g-function

Comment: [The basic definition](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/02/01/) clearly says about complex-valued `a,b,c`.

Comment: Concerning the calculation see https://www.math.ucla.edu/~mason/research/pearson_final.pdf

Comment: Does this answer your question?: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#2398

Comment: @user64494 no it doesn't

Comment: hmmm...seems there are lots of options. from @MichaelE2 's reference: "The hypergeometric functions use functional equations, stable recurrence relations, series expansions, asymptotic series, and Padé approximants. Methods from NSum and NIntegrate are also sometimes used." Judging by `GeneralUtilities\`PrintDefinitions@Hypergeometric2F1`, it's implemented as a kernel function. this might mean that only someone at wolfram could tell you which option is used when—unless someone knows better spelunking techniques?